# I have a compatibility problem with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> /home/franck-jordan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1e7bf2c20410e55f5582b689be396894/transformed/material-1.8.0/res/values/values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall'

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             41,4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

we have been developing a flutter application since 2020 and today during the migration to version 3 we have a compatibility issue between the package and with our sdk

Comment: Please try to add more information and data from the error logs. This might not be enough for us to help you.

Comment: Have you looked if the package has an updated version (if it's some external package)?

Comment: yes all my packages which are up to date have versions compatible with other packages